# C++ input error with switch statment and function

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

I don't know why but my code is not working when I sign out a book and click a number and then try to sign in a book it says I have the number one choice(Python book) even if i click  any other option. I don't know why.It's probably something dumb so please go easy on me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string book;
void menu(){
    cout << "*********Menu*********";
    cout << "\n1) Sign out book";
    cout << "\n2) sign in book";
    cout << "\n3) See my books";
    cout << "\n4) Exit";
    
    }
void book1(){
    book = {"Computer Science"};
}
void book2(){
    book = {"Programming with C++"};
}
void book3(){
    book = {"Python Programming"};
}
int main(){
    //Vars
    int choice;
    do
    {
        menu();
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            int book_choice;
            cout << "\n**********************";
            cout << "\n1) Computer Science";
            cout << "\n2) Programming with C++";
            cout << "\n3) Python Programming";
            cin >> book_choice;
            switch (book_choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    book1();
                case 2:
                    book2();
                case 3:
                    book3();
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
           cout << "\n**********************";
           cout << "\nSigned out books: ";
           cout << book;
            //add books
        case 3:
            cout << "\n**********************";
        
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
    
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the input to produce it? How is what happens different from what you expect? There are no `break;` statements after many of the cases. If you don't want them to fall through to the next case you need them.

Comment: You forgot your `break` statements at the end of each `case`, so it will fall through from case 1 into case 2 and case 3 and then the default block, and eventually break.  Not sure this is your problem, but it's definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the `book_choice` switch:

```
        switch (book_choice)
        {
            case 1:
                book1();
                // missing break;
            case 2:
                book2();
                // missing break;
            case 3:
                book3();
                // missing break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

You forgot to use `break;` after each case. The default behaviour in a switch  is to fall through and execute the next case. That means you always end up executing `book3()` and setting your book to `"Python Programming"`.